# python class to print bash colors

Tags: python, string, class, printing, colors

I have python scripts that will print to screen, and sometimes I want them bold, or green, and sometimes both bold and green. But I can't seem to figure out how to do both.

```
class colortext():
    def __init__(self, text:str):
        self.text = text
        self.ending = '\033[0m'

    def bold(self):
        return '\033[1m' + self.text + self.ending

    def green(self):
        return '\033[92m' + self.text + self.ending


print(colortext('hello').bold().green())

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'green'
```

Comment: They aren't `bash` colors; they're ANSI escape sequences processed by your terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're returning a string in the `bold` and `green` methods. I think you actually want to return a reference to the `colortext` object itself. So modify the text in those methods and return `self`. Also if you want it to print the string when you call it in `print`, define the `__str__` function. Try:

```
class colortext():
    def __init__(self, text:str):
        self.text = text
        self.ending = '\033[0m'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def bold(self):
        self.text = '\033[1m' + self.text + self.ending
        return self

    def green(self):
        self.text = '\033[92m' + self.text + self.ending
        return self

print(colortext('hello').bold().green())
```

Comment: It looks like Java :D

Answer (score 3):

I think a better strategy would be for your methods to add control sequences to a list that is used to construct the final string in a `__str__` method:

```
class ColorText():
    def __init__(self, text:str):
        self.text = text
        self.ending = '\033[0m'
        self.sequences = []
    def bold(self):
        self.sequences.append('\033[1m')
        return self
    def green(self):
        self.sequences.append('\033[92m')
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(self.sequences) + self.text + self.ending  # ''.join(chain would probably work better
```